# Liferay Event to Force Render

Tags: javascript, ajax, liferay, ipc, portlet

I have a Liferay portlet that I perform some actions in via AJAX.  When I handle those actions in serverResource I want to force all the clients to render.  I've tried a few things but they only seem to work per client.  What I mean by client is a user in my site performing the action (i.e. clicking a button to change the status of an entity in a search container).

I tried using client side IPC by firing an event when the entity is updated. I fire the event when my AJAX call was successful, but the event doesn't get caught by my other client (a second browser I have open to the same page) so it doesn't refresh unless I refresh the page which I do NOT want to do.

I looked at configuring sender/receiver portlet (my one portlet is the sender and receiver) but that looks like it required for me to submit actions which would cause my page to refresh, so can't use that.  I did call include from processAction thinking it would trigger a render for all the clients but only worked on the client that make the ajax request.

At this point, I don't see how I can force all clients to refresh unless I setup like an ajax polling routine, which might be my only path forward but any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

JSR 286 standardizes on server-side IPC, there's no Ajax dynamic refresh of single portlets on the screen. You'd have to make your own portlets aware of events that you'll trigger yourself through JS and can't rely on anything (standardized) out-of-the-box from a portal container.

AFAIK serveResource can't trigger events (but I didn't double check with the spec), if it did, an event would certainly not trigger any render through Ajax without custom code on your end